# Connect Gmail API using Cloud Functions in nodejs gcp console

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to follow the [google blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/adding-custom-intelligence-to-gmail-with-serverless-on-gcp) to clasify the messages that arrive to gmail and mark them if an image of a bird is present here is the code [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-gmail-nodejs). Since the authinit and the callback are in the same index.js file what should be the entry-point and the trigger.

Just for reference the last example of google for this task works well until it gets broken here is the previus [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing#0)

I try to run with the different entry-points that have the exports but I don´t understand what function should trigger the function considering that pub/sub should activate the function with each new message on Gmail. I think I need to initialize the gmail watch but I don't know how. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was ablo to deploy the function running on the entry point oauth2init `gcloud functions deploy index --region=us-east1 --runtime=nodejs16 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --entry-point=oauth2init` now when I click on the trigger I get the error "Your client does not have permission to get URL /oauth2callback?code=4/"